# How to change the position of letters in a word in an input string

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i am trying to make a program wherein i want to swap/change the position of the input word: 
for example:
input word:  overflows
    output:  vorelfwos
 I want to swap out the 1st and 2nd letters the 3rd and 4th and so on, and if it has a letter at the end that has no partner for swapping, i want to just leave it as is. Can somebody help me? i will be using c# btw.

Comment: Sounds like homework.. What have you tried? and where are you stuck

Comment: Have a read of [ask]. Introduce the problem, *show what you've tried*, and explain where you're stuck. This currently just reads as 'do my work for me'.

Comment: I literally can't come up with anything, i just dont know how it can be possible to identify the 1st, 2nd or the 3rd letter in a word.

Answer (score 0):

C# strings have an [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), called [`System.String.Chars`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
char letter = "Hello World"[0];
```

`letter` is now `H`.

But strings are immutable, so you can't change a character like this:

```
string myString = "Hello";

myString[1] = 'R'; // Produces an error.
```

So I would suggest using a [`System.Text.StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx), so here is an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) using it:

```
public static string Swap(this string str, int charToSwapA, int charToSwapB)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder(str);
    oldCharToSwapA = stringBuilder[charToSwapA];
    stringBuilder[charToSwapA] = stringBuilder[charToSwapB];
    stringBuilder[charToSwapB] = stringBuilder[oldCharToSwapA];
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
string myString = "dello WorlH".Swap(0, 10);
```

`myString` is now `"Hello World"`.